# How to detect if text value of an HTML input is keyword of something with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, keyword

Is there any way to get estimated text value in input element within JavaScript? Just like on YouTube, you don't need to write the whole video name, just write keyword of it and it will also search

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it. This is my HTML code for the input:

```
<div id="searchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." title="Search..." id="searchInput" oninput="getText()">
</div>
```

And that's JavaScript:

```
function getText() {
let searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
if(searchInput.value == 1*1 || What does 1*1 equal to || one times one || 1 times 1) {
alert("1*1 equals to 1!");
}}
```

**Someone has idea on how to do it?**

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete?

Comment: @mplungjan not really, I mean keywords so you can type phrases similar to each other and it will still alert

Comment: Please elaborate. Give a step by step of what you mean. I have no idea

Comment: So, for example, if you want to know what does 6*7 equal to, you can type "6*7", "6 times 7", "what does 6*7 equals" and the answer will be always 42.

Comment: Are you referring to javascript's eval() function?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does the kinds of evaluations that Google does in the search field.

Comment: How would you define "similar to each other"? Sounds like you need any server-side endpoint that generates this list

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page content is available
  const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');
  searchInput.addEventListener('input', function() { // so we can use "this"
    let val = this.value.trim();
    val = val.replace(/[^0-9\-\+\/\%\*,e]/,''); // only allow digits and operators
    this.value = val;
    try {
      const res = eval(val);
      result.textContent = (res) ? res : "";
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="searchBar">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." title="Search..." id="searchInput" />
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```